# Unwanted sign on each line of worksheet

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I don't know what the hotkey I accidentally clicked, but this `«¶` looking sign appeared on every line of code, and there are grey dots instead of spaces in the code.

[image: Click here to see the snapshot]

How can I get rid of those characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL Developer, go to Tools->Preferences (or on Mac, find that under the SQL Developer menu). Expand the Code Editor section and click on Display. Untick "Show whitespace characters" (second checkbox in the list).

[image]

You can check for defined shortcuts under Preferences, in the Shortcut Keys section. On Mac there isn't one for this, but Windows has it as <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, which will also toggle them off if you don't want to go through the preference pane.